# Как windows отображает окна приложений ? Не нагружая GPU

Tags: windows, ui

Сразу прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но мне интересно.
Если смотреть диспетчер задач, приложения не нагружают GPU.
Хотя во многих приложениях много различной графики.
Почему так происходит.
Объясните пожалуйста.
Как Windows отображает окна?.
[image: Скрин]

Comment: «много различной графики» — например? Пробовали какую-нибудь реально тяжёлую анимацию запускать?

Comment: если обычное приложение (какой то блокнотик или приложение, которое притворяется мессенджером) нагружает GPU, то это очень плохое приложение, которое занимается не своей работой. Если это игра с 3д графикой, отображает 4к видео с аппаратным декодированием или приложение, которое считает биткоины - то это нормально, что оно  будет грузить процессор. Сама же винда свои окна просто рисует точками и линиями. А для этого много вычислительных возможностей не нужно.

Comment: Как правило графика в таких приложениях не занимает много вычислительных ресурсов, к тому же оптимизирована. Если в окне ничего не меняется, то окно не будет перерисовываться, а если меняется, то может так же происходить частичная перерисовка. Но если взять окно, которые оперирует множеством элементов - к примеру двигает непрерывно по экрану сто кнопок, то сразу увидите загрузку CPU или GPU.